# How to increase the spacing between the item and sub-item in latex?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, enumitem

I have the following `LaTeX` code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
\setlength\itemsep{0.5em}

\item Test item 1

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
   \item Test subitem 1.1
   \item Test subitem 1.2
   \item Test subitem 3.3
\end{enumerate}

\item Test item 2

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
    \item Test subitem 2.1
    \item Test subitem 2.2
    \item Test subitem 2.3
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I managed to increase the space between items as follows:

[image]

How do I increase the spacing between an item and sub-item?

Comment: Since you're using `enumitem` already, you can set `itemsep=...` in the options -- there's no need to use a separate `\setlength` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my point of view the spacings between the nested levels are quite good and there's no need to change the separations, but the space above (and below!) an item list is controlled by `topsep`, which can be set with `topsep=...` in the optional argument to `enumerate`

If this length should be valid for all 2nd level lists, use `\setlist[enumerate,2]{topsep=...}` where `...` stands for 'any' desired value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.},itemsep=0.5em]

\item Test item 1
\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.},topsep=25pt]
   \item Test subitem 1.1
   \item Test subitem 1.2
   \item Test subitem 3.3
\end{enumerate}

\item Test item 2

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
    \item Test subitem 2.1
    \item Test subitem 2.2
    \item Test subitem 2.3
\end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Christian Hupfer, was exactly what I needed! I would like to congratulate you for their knowledge of Latex!